# Is there a name for a reverse push-up executed by pushing with the elbows?

Tags: exercise, movements, terminology

Is there a name for a [reverse push-up](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-Reverse-Push-Ups) executed by pushing with the elbows?

[Example](https://youtu.be/cszJcRz5UB0):

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the name is significant?

Comment: @rrirower communication convenience

Comment: In my opinion, if I were naming that exercise, I'd provide the name of the body part it works and the type of equipment it uses as part of its name.  Something like: 'Lying reverse push ups for the upper back between two benches'.  As it's currently written, it's kind of vague without seeing the actual movement.

Answer (score 1):

Elbow assisted Victorian cross.

It's a Victorian cross, with reduced levers by sitting the weight on the elbows instead of the hands and it is assisted with the feet as support.

Comment: Doing it on TRX or dip bars/benches or rings doesn't change the name.... A bicep curl is still a bicep curl regardless of the equipment used.